# Defining an 'optional' description list environment

Tags: spacing, enumitem, description

I'm trying to create a variant of the `description` environment that coerces any present description to be on the next line.  I can't seem to get the vertical spacing right when there's no description for the term, however.

If an item in a list doesn't have any body text, how can I forgo its corresponding vskip?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{classlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[classlist]{
  before     = \itshape\small,
  font       = \normalfont,
  leftmargin = 1em,
  labelsep   = 1em,
  itemsep    = 0pt,
  style      = nextline,
  labelwidth = 0pt % always bump to next line
}

\def\descr{Class description.  More class description.  There's so
  much description here.  It's very descriptive.  This class will be
  the most descriptive.  It'll be great.}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{classlist}
  \item[Class Name]
  \item[Class Name] \descr
  \item[Class Name]
  \item[Class Name]
\end{classlist}

% This version displays correctly, but...
\begin{description}[                    %
  font=\normalfont,                  %
  leftmargin=1em,                 %
  labelsep=1em,                %
  before=\itshape\small,    %
  itemsep=0pt            %
]                     %
\item[Class Name]  % i'd like to avoid this manual ~\newline cruft
\item[Class Name] ~\newline \descr
\item[Class Name]
\item[Class Name]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enlarge the labelwidth so that the label takes the whole first line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{classlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[classlist]{
  before     = \itshape\small,
  font       = \normalfont,
  leftmargin = 1em,
  labelsep   = 1em,
  itemsep    = 0pt,
  labelwidth = \dimexpr\linewidth-1em % always bump to next line
}

\def\descr{Class description.  More class description.  There's so
  much description here.  It's very descriptive.  This class will be
  the most descriptive.  It'll be great.}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{classlist}
  \item[Class Name]
  \item[Class Name] \descr
  \item[Class Name]
  \item[Class Name]
\end{classlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]